# What is the best way to get progress from static non-Android class?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application which calls a long-lasting (several hours) static class method. This class is a general purpose class and should know nothing about Android and its API. My application obviously should display the progress of this action. What is the best way to organize interaction between `Activity` and this class? I consider defining some `IProgress` interface, implement it in `Activity` and let static class use it to update its status. But may be there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call the long-lasting operation within an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

1. You could take in the `IProgress` callback as a constructor to your
   `AsyncTask`.
2. In the `doInBackground()`, do your long-lasting task,
   get its status and publish it using `publishProgress()` In your
   onProgressUpdate, do a `callback.displayProgress()`.
3. This `displayProgress()` would have the UI code to display the progress.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Best way to add External Jars to your Android Projectis:

> - Create a folder call 'lib' into you project root folder
>
>   - Copy your Jar files to the lib folder
>   - Now right click on Project -> JavaBuild Path ->Add Jar -> Select the project-> select lib directory-> select the jar file-> click ok button. This will add the jar into your  project